# Inclusion-Exclusion Question.

Tags: discrete-mathematics

Consider 100 students, each taking at least one of the courses: art, biology and computing.

Let 20 students take both art and biology, 31 students take both art and computing, and 24 students take both biology and computing.

Furthermore, 85 students take at least one of art and biology, 78 students
take at least one of art and computing, and 84 students take at least one of
biology and computing.

How many students are taking all three courses?

So I'm trying to narrow this into sets with A being art, B being biology and C being computing.

I know that | A U B | - | A N B | gives me the students in either just Art or just Biology, and | A U C | - | A N C | gives me students in just art and computing, but I'm honestly completely lost after that.

Comment: @S.S Can I have a hint on how to get the individual sets? Am I on the right track with taking the difference of | A U B | - | A N B | ?

Comment: Note that $|A\cup B|-|A\cap B|=|A|+|B|$ and $(|A\cup B|-|A\cap B|-|B\cup C|+|B\cap C|)/2+|A\cup C|-|B\cup C|)/2=|A|$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint:**  Note that $|A\cup B|+|A\cap B|=|A|+|B|$ and $|B\cup C|+|B\cap C|=|B|+|C|$. Subtracting the two equations we get $$|A\cup B|+|A\cap B|-|B\cup C|-|B\cap C|=|A|-|C|$$  But notice that $|A\cup C|-|A\cap C|=|A|+|C|$. Adding this equation to the previous one we get $$(|A\cup B|+|A\cap B|-|B\cup C|-|B\cap C|+|A\cup C|+|A\cap C|)/2=|A|$$

You can certainly generalize the argument by simply permuting the letters.

After you find those you just stick them into the formula

$$|A|+|B|+|C|-|A\cap B|-|A\cap C|-|B\cap C|+|A\cap B\cap C|=100$$.

More simply we could just note that $$(|A\cup B|+|A\cap B|+|B\cup C|+|B\cap C|+|A\cup C|+|A\cap C|)/2=|A|+|B|+|C|$$

Comment: Thanks, I'm just kind of confused on where the /2 comes from?

Comment: When you add the two equations |A|-|C| and |A|+|C| you get 2|A|.

Comment: Oh wow... my bad

Comment: (|A∪B|−|A∩B|−|B∪C|+|B∩C|+|A∪C|−|B∪C|)/2=|A| why is the last set |BUC| shouldn't it be | A N C |

Comment: Your right. Its a typo.

Comment: I plugged in all the numbers and I got 89 for | A N B N C | which seems unusually high, did I do something wrong?

Comment: I also got 89. I think there might be a problem with the conditions given in your problem. Notice how $|A\cap B\cap C|>|A\cap B|$ even though $A\cap B\subseteq A\cap B\cap C$

Comment: $|A|+|B|=|A\cup B|+|A\cap B|\ne|A\cup B|-|A\cap B|$.

Comment: Whoops my mistake

Answer (score 1):

Hint:

- If $85$ students take at least one of art and biology, then how many take computing but neither of the other two?
- How many are only taking a single subject?
- How many are taking two or three subjects?
- Why is that last number smaller than $20+31+24$?